# Dynamically inserted assemblyIdentity version attribute

Tags: .net, visual-studio, com, side-by-side

I'm working on some changes to support side-by-side assemblies for .NET COM Interop components loaded by a native (Delphi) application. For my .NET .dll, I've added an app.manifest in Visual Studio, and specified the necessary  element.

The issue I have, is the `<assemblyIdentity>` node has a hardcoded version number that has to match my assembly version (AFAICT). This means whenever I update my assembly version, I have to have the app.manifest match. This is particularly annoying/hard to do when we're using asterisks in the assembly version (so they get generated at build time)

How should I handle keeping app.manifest in sync?

Comment: Write a little app to read the assembly and update the manifest file, call it via an after build event?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm embedding the manifest as a resource, not keeping it as a separate file. Do you mean using a "resource editor" to update it after the assembly is built?

Comment: No I did not mean that, he shudders. Looks like you situtaion is even more complicated than it first appeared

Comment: Yeah, it seems like assembly version wildcards + embedded manifests are mutually exclusive unless a resource editor hack is used.